# How to pass value from html to url using jstl ,href="edittheme?id=value1"

Tags: javascript, html, jstl

```
<input type="text" name="value1" id="value1"/>

<a href="edittheme?id=value1" title="Edit Event">Edit</a></td>
```

The value1 is set using script

```
document.getElementById("value1").value = themeId;
```

Can someone help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to select the `<a>` using JavaScript and then change the `href` attribute:

**JS**

```
var value = document.getElementById("value1").value;
document.getElementById("linkEdit").href = 'edittheme?id=' + value;
```

**HTML**

```
<a href="" id="linkEdit" title="Edit Event">Edit</a>
```

Comment: thank you. that solves my problem.
how can i pass a value from input box if needed?

Comment: is there a way to pass the input box value.